# Simple table sorting using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is a simple and clean script for sorting a specific column in a table. You could edit and parametrize it to add more customization, but I wanted to share the base concept.

Base concept (I think its a pretty cool 3 line code):

```
t = document.getElementById('myTable');
[...t.tBodies[0].rows] //Transforming HTMLCollection to an Array
.sort( (a,b) => a.cells[0].textContent < b.cells[0].textContent)
.forEach(r => t.tBodies[0].appendChild(r)) //Appending the rows themselves, so the table is reordered without needing to create any new element
```

Parametrization example:

```
function sortTableColumn(tableID, columnIndex){
    t = document.getElementById(`#${tableID}`);
    [...t.tBodies[0].rows]
    .sort( (a,b) => a.cells[columnIndex].textContent < b.cells[columnIndex].textContent)
    .forEach(r => t.tBodies[columnIndex].appendChild(r))
}
```

Concerns:

- Performance: is the use of spread operator ok here? Or is `Array.from` preferred?
- Visual sorting: Since you're re-appending each element one by one, in a large table the user would see the table arranging until it is done. I couldn't think of a way of "one shotting" the appending without affecting performance too much. Maybe adding a loading overlay is the best solution?
- What if we're dealing with a table with 1000+ records? What could go wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/nu0q62br/22/

Table (any table with one body should work):

```html
     <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you add the html table example too :)

Comment: @G.aziz sure, added the fiddle too

Comment: *"user would see the table arranging"* ...  not at all likely to be visible. For larger set will get better performance sorting outside the dom and replacing tbody all at one time

Comment: @charlietfl yes but, is replacing the whole tbody at once better performance?